# What are "O-hydrocarbons"? A pharma translator's question (Russian to English, "О-углеводороды")

Tags: terminology, hydrocarbons

A translator colleague is translating from Russian a plan for study of a number of leachable and extractable substances (pharmacology). This Russian text mentions one particular class of chemicals which theoretically could become leachables:

> "Hydrocarbons (alkanes, alkenes, alkynes, **O-hydrocarbons**)".

She can't understand what this could mean.

The Russian term is **О-углеводороды**.

> [image]

Comment: My guess is cyclic as opposed to linear HC ie cyclohexane.

Comment: I've never seen this term in Russian literature before. My first guess would be that it's any oxygen-substituted hydrocarbon ("кислородозамещенный углеводород"); it also might be leading zero (`0`) and then it might refer to [un]saturation degree, e.g. another name for alkanes ("насыщенный углеводород"); @NightWriter 's version also makes a lot of sense ("циклический углеводород").

Comment: Your first guess was correct, @andselisk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My fellow translator sent a letter to the authors, and they replied that they used this term to stand for "oxygen-substituted hydrocarbons", just like andselisk suggested.